# UnauthorizedAccessException Error

Tags: c#

Fellow User,
Trying to write to a file - from a console application in Visual C# - using System.IO, when I encountered this error:`UnauthorizedAccessException unhandled` (which was not present in the courseware I was watching).
I am aware that this is quite a simple problem and have looked for the solution on msdn.com yet all I was able to find was that my problem was a security error or System.IO error, nothing about how to fix the problem.

This is the code:

```
string someText = "I want to write this to a text file!";

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Keagan\Desktop\
    C#projects\UnderstandingNamespaces", someText);
```

Regards K.Roe

Comment: Please share us the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no way to help you without the actual code.

Comment: Code? Stacktrace?

Comment: Where is the file to be stored (in what folder on what disk)? Does the user (probably the program is running under your user) running the program have access to write files in that location?

Comment: Can you edit the file manually?

Comment: Yes I can I made sure that is was not a Read-Only file. Thank you.

Comment: I will share an example yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced exactly the same problem. 
You have two solution:

First One: Make sure that you have full permission on the folder.

```
Go to folder -> Right click -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Select user -> Edit -> Allow Full Control.
```

Second Solution (Most Probably):

```
string someText = "I want to write this to a text file!";
```

make sure that you `someText` variable hold the file name with extension. for exmaple: `MyFile.txt` or something like that. In addition to that, make sure that you `filePath` is correct.

I faced the same problem, but I don't know why visual studio throw this strange exception.

Comment: Thank you, your first solution fixed the solution, the second one wouldn't have worked though I need someText to hold the content of what I want written to the file.

Comment: Welcome bro, if my solution fixed your problem, please don't forget to mark the question as answered :D.